# insufficient data in "D" message

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy scoped sessions to work with a postgresql 9.4 database. 
Sometimes I get an error that says "DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) insufficient data in "D" message". I cannot reproduce this error and it happens in an unpredictable way.
After looking at he postgres log files, this error occurs shortly after postgresql logs "could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer". I guess that means that the connection was cut from the application side. But I don't see anything that could cause this.

Answer (score 1):

It's time to break out your network tools. You have errors on both end that suggests something caused your connection to drop.

It might be hardware, drivers, some bug in your software stack or a proxy / firewall deciding it didn't like the look of your connection and killed it. It's unlikely to be PostgreSQL itself or any of your Python code.

Fire up [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and take a look at the packets going back and fore. Ideally on both ends of the connection. That should give you a good indication of where the problem is.